# R: RegEx for coordinates

Tags: regex, r

New to R.I am using str_extract_all from the stringr package to try and extract coordinates that are currently in this format:

```
coordinate <- "{u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [-2.824602, 53.235397]}"
```

I would like to extract the first coordinate in a corresponding column next to this text, and the second coordinate in another column.

I would like to use a perl expression to extract, but a little stuck on how to do this.

result would look like:

```
coordinate x y
"{u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [-2.824602, 53.235397]}"    -2.824602    53.235397
```

Comment: The stringr package has a perl option

Comment: so do the base R regex functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks to work:

```
> str_extract_all(coordinate, perl("-?\\d+\\.?\\d*"))
[[1]]
[1] "-2.824602" "53.235397"
```

Piece-by-piece: `-?` 0 or 1 negative signs, `\\d+` zero or more digits, `\\.?` 0 or 1 decimal points (escaped since it's a regex meta character), `\\d+` one or more digits.

If `coordinate` is a vector, you can get it to a matrix like this (not nearly as fancy as `qdapRegex`):

```
matrix(as.numeric(unlist(
      str_extract_all(rep(coordinate, 4), perl("-?\\d+\\.?\\d*"))
)), ncol = 2, byrow = T)
          [,1]    [,2]
[1,] -2.824602 53.2354
[2,] -2.824602 53.2354
[3,] -2.824602 53.2354
[4,] -2.824602 53.2354
```

Comment: Whoops, forgot to escape the `.`. And I'll change that last `+` to a `*`. It still won't match decimals without a leading 0...

Comment: no, now it matches `67.` . It isn't a valid number i think. Change your pattern as `-?(?:\\d+\\.)?\\d+`

Answer (score 5):

That looks like a json in the form of a character string, so I would recommend the easy route and use one of the json parsing functions.

```
RJSONIO::fromJSON(coordinate)[[2]]
[1] -2.824602 53.235397
```

This way you also get numeric values in the result, instead of characters

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple method using `qdapRegex` and `read.csv`

```
library(qdapRegex)
read.csv(text = rm_square(coordinate, extract = TRUE)[[1]], header = FALSE)
##          V1      V2
## 1 -2.824602 53.2354
```

Or if you insist on `stringr`, could also do

```
read.csv(text = str_extract_all(coordinate, perl("(?<=\\[)[^']+(?=\\])"))[[1]], header = FALSE)
```

Comment: `qdap` is starting to make more sense to me nowadays. It was tough at first

Answer (score 2):

You could use `str_extract_all` function from `stringr` library.

```
> str_extract_all(coordinate, perl("-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?"))
[[1]]
[1] "-2.824602" "53.235397"
```

- `-?` An optional hyphen.
- `\\d+` One or more digits.
- `(?:\\.\\d+)?` Optional non-capturing group used to match the decimal part if exists.
  We must need to escape the dot because in regex , dot is a special meta character which matches any character. To match a literal dot, you must need to escape that.
- The reason for putting the pattern used to match the decimal part in a optional group means , so that it would match even the number which has a single digit.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake--I think it's fixed now. Your regex will extract `.4` or `-.4` as just `4`.

Comment: i think there must be a number before the dot,like   0.4

Comment: Hopefully... depending on the data source.

Answer (score 1):

```
> str_extract_all(coordinate, "[-.[:digit:]]+")
[[1]]
[1] "-2.824602"  "53.235397"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `gsub`

```
 scan(text=gsub('[^[]+[[]([-0-9,. ]+)[[:punct:]]+',
                 '\\1', coordinate),sep=",", quiet=TRUE)
 #[1] -2.824602 53.235397
```